# How to call parent widget in GTKmm?

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

I'm programming in libgtkmm3 right now.

My question is, how to call the parent widget from a Gtk::Box.

I've got a Gtk::Box:

```
class PackBox1 : public Gtk::Box
```

I've got a Gtk::Frame with PackBox3:

```
Window::Window()
: frame1(topic + " (" + std::to_string(active) + "/" + std::to_string(nummax) + ")")
{
    PackBox *pPackBox1;
    pPackBox1 = Gtk::make_managed<PackBox>(false, 0, Gtk::PACK_EXPAND_PADDING);
    m_box1.pack_start(*pPackBox1, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    frame1.add(m_box1);
    frame1.set_border_width(10);
}
```

How can I set frame1.set_label("New text") from within pPackBox1 like this:

```
class PackBox1 : public Gtk::Box
{
    frame1.set_label("Test");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you simply pass a reference to the parent in `PackBox1`'s constructor (and optionnaly) save it as a member?

Comment: @BobMorane: Yes, I tried to pass it, but I only got an error.

Comment: If you could create a minimal and reproducible example for the code that gives you the error, as well as add the error message and add this information to your question, I could help you.

Comment: Please add your code (which should be minimal and reproduce your issue) inlined with your question. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to write a meaningful question on SO, especially the _Help others reproduce the problem_ section.